# VBA - referring range in other worksheet using Worksheet_Change - Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I need to refer the range in different worksheet, so I have used Worksheet_change event but getting error 1004. Below is the code -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim inputSheetName As String
    Dim dataSheetName As String
    inputSheetName = Range("Selected_State").Worksheet.Name
    dataSheetName = Range("Selected_City").Worksheet.Name
End Sub
```

here Range-"Selected_State" is range in Sheet1 and "
Range - "Selected_City is range in Sheet2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range is always within a specific worksheet. If you use

```
Range("Selected_State")
```

then Excel assumes that this range is in the active sheet. It is exactly the same as this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Selected_State")
```

So if you want to know in which worksheet a named range is you should use this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("Selected_State").RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name
```

*Note: This does only work if the name is within the workbook scope but not when within a worksheet's scope. Therefore you would need to loop through all worksheets to find that name.*

Comment: Thanks a lot I am able to access it now

Comment: @VinayChhabra You might consider accepting this as solution to the question so other users know that it is solved. See [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)